# How to prevent gulp-sass to create folder "sass" after I gulp my scss file to css file?

Tags: gulp, gulp-sass

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('sass', function() {
  gulp.src('src/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./src/css'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch('src/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
});
```

I want to put css file into folder src/css. But after gulp, css file will be in src/css/sass catalogue. How to prevent gulp to create sass folder? I just want file in src/css catalogue, not src/css/sass.

Answer (score 11):

I am assuming you have a `sass` directory inside `src`.

By default `gulp.src()` considers everything before the `**` as the `base`. Everything after `base`, including parts matched by `**`, will be in the destination file path.

Change your sass task to

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {
  gulp.src('src/sass/**/*.scss')
             // ^-- now sass directory is part of 'base'
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./src/css'));
});
```

Read more about `base` [here](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#optionsbase).

Comment: Thank you!  It have worded as I think!